# Magento2: Not able to check uncheck a Checkbox value while editing the page?

Tags: magento2, checkbox, product-edit, input

I am not able to check and uncheck a Checkbox value and save in edit page in Magento2:

My input field:

```
 <label class="check_tick">Shipping
                    <input type="checkbox" name="product[shiping]" id="shiping" value= 1 <?php if($product_coll->getShipingValue() == 1){ echo "checked='checked'"; }?> class="checkboxvalue">
                    <span class="checkmarkng"></span>
                </label>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May I know where you defined this variable $product_coll

Comment: I am getting the value in same file..

Comment: try this one <label class="check_tick">Shipping
                    <input type="checkbox" name="product[shiping]" id="shiping" value= "1" <?php if($product_coll->getShipingValue() == 1){ echo "checked='checked'"; }?> class="checkboxvalue">
                    <span class="checkmarkng"></span>
                </label>

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: If I use the input type as "text" it is working, but for checkbox is not working.

Comment: can you print this echo $product_coll->getShipingValue() ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105438/discussion-between-jinesh-and-amy).